# LibSodium dependency in CMake doesn't resolve in Docker container

Tags: c, docker, cmake, libsodium

I'm trying to build my C project using Docker and CMake. CMake'ing using `cmake . && cmake --build .` works fine on my system (MacOS), using the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (PROJECTNAME)

# Include libsodium
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake/modules")
find_package(sodium REQUIRED)

include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "build")

add_library(project STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(project sodium)
```

The Findsodium.cmake, required by `find_package(sodium REQUIRED)`
 is a direct copy of the file on [the libsodium GitHub](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/master/contrib/Findsodium.cmake).

Now I'm trying to build this using `docker build` and the following Dockerfile (I know some packages it installs are redundant):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY . /project
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  libsodium18 \
  curl
RUN cd project && cmake .
RUN cmake --build .
```

Unfortunately this fails with the following message:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find sodium (missing: sodium_LIBRARY_RELEASE sodium_LIBRARY_DEBUG
  sodium_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/Findsodium.cmake:226 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

When I run a normal docker container and perform the steps manually the same error is thrown. Somehow libsodium can not be located, even though it is properly installed:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep sodium
libsodium.so.18 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.18
```

Anyone with experience using **Findsodium.cmake** on Ubuntu, or other, that can give some insight?

**EDIT**: after the suggestion of LinPy I added `libsodium-dev` as a package to be installed and the error changes slightly:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find sodium (missing: sodium_LIBRARY_RELEASE
  sodium_LIBRARY_DEBUG) (found version "

  #ifndef sodium_version_H

  #define sodium_version_H



  #include "export.h"



  #define SODIUM_VERSION_STRING "1.0.8"

  ...
  ...

  ")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/Findsodium.cmake:226 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

It seems that some things could be found now, but not the debug and release library?

Dockerfile looks like this now:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY . /project
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  libsodium18 \ # also tried it without this line
  libsodium-dev \
  curl
RUN cd project && cmake .
RUN cmake --build .
```

**EDIT 2**: Adding `pkg-config` as well fixes the second error.

Comment: It's possible that within `Findsodium.cmake`, the `find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)` call is failing (silently), which could explain why the `sodium_*` variables are not getting populated...

Comment: That could be. Maybe the EDIT I added helps with understanding what's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to your `dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libsodium-dev pkg-config
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added it to the list of installs and have a different error message. Unfortunately not a very helpful one to me. Could you see if it rings a bell? See EDIT in original question ^.

Comment: A google search on the new error gave me the solution of adding `pkg-config` to the install list as well. This seems to work! Could you add that to your answer? Then I'll mark it as solution.